# ParseCrashReporting crash reports do not appear on dashboard

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Done everything as tutorial mentions, and I can see in my console:

> Apr 19 23:28:14 MyMac AppName[8052] : [Info][Crash Reporting]: Started Processing Pending Crash Reports
>
> Apr 19 23:28:14 MyMac AppName[8052] : [Info][Crash Reporting]: Started Sending Crash Report for Date: 2015-04-19 20:28:07
>
> Apr 19 23:28:17 MyMac AppName[8052] : [Info][Crash Reporting]: Did Send Crash Report for Date: 2015-04-19 20:28:07 +0000
>
> Apr 19 23:28:17 MyMac AppName[8052] : [Info][Crash Reporting]: Processed All Pending Crash Reports

But the crash report is not showing up. Ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Took the crash reports THREE DAYS to show up.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with Android application. In logs CrashReporting showing that is enabled and that is sending crash reports, but none are shown on dashboard :(

I tried to change Parse lib from latest 1.9.1 to earlier 1.9.0 but no effect.

Comment: It was reported on Parse bug reporting, they resolved the problem. It was something wrong on their site. Now I have all my crashes visible.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it can take anywhere from a few minutes to a few hours for crash reports to show up.

Comment: Strange.  Are you sure you implemented crash reporting correctly?